# How to find element in string(char array) and double it?

Tags: visual-c++

I need to: 
 -input string
-find in that string element ">"
-double it.

Example:
imput: 123>21
output: 123>>21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use string::find and string::insert.

```
const char *c_str = "123>45";
std::string a = std::string(c_str);
std::string b = ">";
a.insert(a.find(b), b);
c_str = a.c_str();
```